# Python sorting mechanism

Tags: python, permutation

Is there a way to get all combinations of a string list?

```
Input: x=list("T", "H", "E")
Output: THE, TEH, HTE, HET, ETH, EHT
```

this is what I got so far I'm pretty new to this:

```py
print("Enter word")
x=input()
print("your word is " + x)
print(list(x))
```

it just need to be sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

print([''.join(x) for x in permutations('THE')])

# ['THE', 'TEH', 'HTE', 'HET', 'ETH', 'EHT']
```

You can use any iterable for `itertools.permutations`, so `'THE'` works, as well as `['T', 'H', 'E']`.